# Keep rows according to condition in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am looking for a code to find rows that matches a condition and keep those rows.

In the image example, I wish to keep all the apples with amt1 => 5 and amt2 < 5. I also want to keep the bananas with amt1 => 1 and amt2 < 5 (highlighted red in image). There are many other fruits in the list that I have to filter for (maybe about 10 fruits).

[image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTfOl.jpg)

Currently, I am filtering it individually (ie. creating a dataframe that filters out the red and small apples and another dataframe that filters out the green and big bananas and using concat to join the dataframes together afterwards). However, this process takes a long time to run because the dataset is huge. I am looking for a faster way (like filtering it in the dataframe itself without having to create a new dataframes). I also have to use column index instead of column names as the column name changes according to the date.

Hopefully what I said makes sense. Would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite sure I understand your requirements because I don't understand how the conditions for the rows to keep are formulated.

One thing you can use to combine multiple criteria for selecting data is the `query` method of the dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['Apple', 5, 1],
    ['Apple', 4, 2], 
    ['Orange', 3, 3], 
    ['Banana', 2, 4], 
    ['Banana', 1, 5]], 
    columns=['Fruits', 'Amt1', 'Amt2'])

df.query('(Fruits == "Apple" & (Amt1 >= 5 & Amt2 < 5)) | (Fruits == "Banana" & (Amt1 >= 1 & Amt2 < 5))')
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help! For this method, is it possible to use the column index instead of the name of the column? Otherwise, is there a code to remove all characters after a certain character for all the column headers? My data set has dates included. So the column headers would be something like "Fruits - Q1 2022" and "Amt1 - 02/2022". If I could remove all characters after " -", I could use this method.

Comment: You can use the `Dataframe.rename` method to rename columns. For example the following command renames all columns to the part before the first dash (if there is any dash, otherwise the column name is kept as is): `dfr.rename(mapper=lambda s: s.split('-')[0], axis='columns')`

Answer (score 0):

You might use `filter` combined with `itertuples` following way

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"x":[1,2,3,4,5],"y":[10,20,30,40,50]})
def keep(row):
    return row[0] >= 2 and row[1] <= 40
df_filtered = pd.DataFrame(filter(keep,df.itertuples())).set_index("Index")
print(df_filtered)
```

gives output

```
       x   y
Index       
2      3  30
3      4  40
4      5  50
```

Explanation: `keep` is function which should return `True` for rows to keep `False` for rows to jettison. `.itertuples()` provides iterable of tuples, which are feed to `filter` which select records where `keep` evaluates to `True`, these selected rows are used to create new `DataFrame`. After that is done I set index so `Index` is corresponding to original `DataFrame`. Depending on your use case you might elect to not set index.

Comment: Thanks for your response! This method works for a single condition. How can it be edited to suit multiple conditions? For example, as shown in the image example, there is the 'fruits' column. I want to filter for two different conditions - one for apples and one for bananas.